# "Library" in German: Bibliothek, Bücherei

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, difference

I know two translations of *library* into German: "Bibliothek" and "Bücherei".

- *Bibliothek* = "systematisch geordnete Sammlung von Büchern" or "Aufbewahrungsort für eine systematisch geordnete Sammlung von Büchern" - DWDS.
- *Bücherei* = "Aufbewahrungsort einer Büchersammlung, kleinere (öffentliche) Bibliothek" - DWDS.

From a simple search it is clear that "Bibliothek" is ten times more in use than "Bücherei".

Hypothesis: city library is *Stadtbücherei*, while university library is *Universitätbibliothek*. I think it is like that. Or can I call a city library a *Stadtbibliothek* and a university library a *Universitätbücherei*?

Comment: Especially in the IT "Bibliothek" can also mean a collection of tools/programs/functions (not books!). For example, the `libaudiocd` contains functions that deal with audio CDs (like play, etc.). This would *not* translate to "Bücherei" but to "Bibliothek". That might be one of the reasons why ["Bibliothek" is more popular than "Bücherei"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=B%C3%BCcherei%2C+Bibliothek&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CB%C3%BCcherei%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBibliothek%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: *Bibliothek* can also just mean *collection of books*. Some German publishers (e.g. Reclam) call their programme *Bibliothek*.

Comment: @Janka: Ist das eine Marketingmetapher, oder nennt man das Programm anderer Verlage auch Bibliothek? Gebräuchlich ist das Wort m.W. nicht, aber ich unterhalte mich auch quasi nie über Verlagsprogramme und höre das Wort fast nie.

Answer (score 7):

*Bücherei* is an older, simpler, non-foreign expression, not being used in academic circles; apart from that, they are largely synonyms. (*Bücherei* always refers to a public library, whereas a *Bibliothek* can be private, too.) *Stadtbibliothek* is totally fine (but not *Universitätsbücherei*), meaning that *Bücherei* is the narrower term.

Comment: So, the hypernym is Bibliothek and Bücherei is the narrower term? In other words, every Bücherei is a Bibliothek but nor reversely?

Comment: In my opinion every Bücherei is a Bibliothek, yes, but not vice versa. You could probably do very well without the term _Bücherei_ altogether.

Comment: [Bücherei](https://www.dwds.de/wb/B%C3%BCcherei#et-1) ist neuer.

Comment: In German Bibliothek is (marginally) older than Bücherei (early 17th versus mid-17th century). In Greek and Latin biblioteca (bibliotheke) is of course much older. Bücherei is simply a German translation of Bibliothek.

Comment: "Älterer Begriff" war nicht im Vergleich zum Wort _Bibliothek_ gemeint, sondern als Gegensatz zu "modern"; sagen wir also "altmodisch" statt älter. Der Begriff kommt meines Wissens aus dem Umfeld der Arbeiterbildungsbewegung bzw. hat jedenfalls dort eine größere Verbreitung erfahren und darf heute als veraltend gelten.

Comment: @Ingmar Hast Du einen Beleg für "darf heute als veraltend gelten"? Bei mir in der Gegend (= Münchner Umland) sind die Büchereien subjektiv deutlich in der Überzahl. Vielleicht ja nur noch hier?

Comment: @Matthias In Österreich sind nach meiner Erfahrung die öffentlichen Bibliotheken definitiv in der Mehrheit: ob das die "Stadtbibliotheken" Graz, Salzburg oder Linz sind, oder die Mehrzahl der kleinen Gemeindebibliotheken: die soweit ersichtlich einzigen großen, die konsequent "Bücherei" im Namen führen sind die "Büchereien Wien" und der "Büchereiverband Österreichs", der -- laut Selbstdarstellung -- "Dachverband der österreichischen Bibliotheken (!)".

Answer (score 5):

From my experience ...

*Bibliothek* is a collection of books *or* an institution that administers that collection *or* a *Bücherei*.

A personal collection of books can also be called *Bibliothek*. But that may originate from an ancient joke, like calling a purse a treasury.
I´m a librarian´s son; I´ll ask.

*Bücherei*<s>, afaik, is a place where the books are stored and administered. It</s> definitely is the narrower term.

---

From my mother, the librarian:

The term *Bücherei* first came up when artisan guilds set up libraries for their members. The term is used for non-private libraries, i.e. libraries that are run by an institution of some kind, be it open to the public or only to selected people (e.g. a *Schulbücherei* where only teachers and pupils of that school have access). *Bücherei* is also the term for the institution that runs that library, if that is its sole purpose.

*Bibliothek* is not only the broader term, but formerly mostly used for classic libraries, where collecting and preserving literature is the focus (so that it´s there when you need it), while *Bücherei* is primarily used for libraries where the focus lies on using the books.

The main difference in brief:
A *Bibliothek* collects books that *may be* needed.
A *Bücherei* keeps those that *are* needed (and dumps those that are not).

Nowadays, they are generally used as synonyms, and there are a lot of former "Städtische Bücherei" that are now a "Städtische Bibliothek".

---

I suppose that´s because *Bibliothek* sounds more sophisticated ... and people are forgetting the difference between the two. But actually, they are synonyms: one Greek, one German.

Comment: Being married to a librarian, I can confirm that. Best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

On the first view there is no difference between a *Bibliothek* and a *Bücherei*

The word „Bibliothek“ has Greek sources ( βιβλιοθήκη (biblio-thḗkē)). [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliothek#Wortherkunft_und_Definition) tells, the *Bücherei* is a     calque  from dutch (1658 by Johann Amos Comenius). Another [article in wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philipp_von_Zesen#Verdeutschungen) mentions Philipp von Zesen as the creator of the word *Bücherei*. The [Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/gesellschaft/zwiebelfisch-neue-woerter-braucht-das-land-a-742873.html) mentions also Philipp von Zesen as the creator of the *Bücherei*.

As a conclusion you may say, *Bibliothek* is a more sophisticated word and is used in more intellectual context (a university library or the private library of a well educated person with     high-minded  books). The *Bücherei* is more used for 'ordinary' book collection.

To avoid misunderstandings: Both words have a positive meaning. If you say, you go to a *Bücherei* you give a well educated image of you (you read books instead of looking TV). But there is also a big chance, that you look for a book for your leisure time. In a Bibliothek you get boot for professional reasons. But is is a smooth transition.

Comment: "If you say, you go to a Bücherei you give a well educated image of you (you read books instead of looking TV)." - although of course, you can also go to a Bücherei to get comic books, board games, sometimes even computer games, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well a "Bücherei" is always a place/building where people can read or lend books. This need not be true for a "Bibliothek". Maybe you have a friend with a large collection of books - you will say "He has a Bibliothek" you will not say "He has a Bücherei".